# createForm() of FormToolKit creates scroll bars

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create a multipage editor looking similar to the manifest editor using the wizard for multipage editors provided by eclipse. The first page is created as follows:

```
void createPage0() {

    Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.DEFAULT);
    composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(composite.getDisplay());
    Form form = toolkit.createForm(composite);
    form.setText("Test Viewer");

    toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form);

    int index = addPage(composite);
    setPageText(index, "editor1");
}
```

When ran with eclipse, the created form has two scroll activ scroll bar, although there is obviously nothing to scroll.

I tried cleaning and refreshing the project. Nothing changed. Help?

Comment: Works OK for me, but I am using Mac OS X which doesn't normally show scroll bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. The composite surrounding form somehow makes the scroll bars. The following code solves the problem.

```
void createPage0() {    
    FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(composite.getDisplay());
    Form form = toolkit.createForm(composite);
    form.setText("Test Viewer");

    toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form);

    int index = addPage(composite);
    setPageText(index, "editor1");
}
```